# X-I.: command not found, and failed to build certain kind of software, what's wrong?

Tags: build, autotools, autoconf, automake, libtool

the error message is as follows:

```
./libtool: line 1129: X-I.: command not found
./libtool: line 1129: X-DLT_CONFIG_H=<config.h>: command not found
./libtool: line 1129: X-DLTDL: command not found
./libtool: line 1129: X-I.: command not found
./libtool: line 1129: X-I.: command not found
./libtool: line 1129: X-Ilibltdl: command not found
./libtool: line 1129: X-I./libltdl: No such file or directory
./libtool: line 1129: X-I./libltdl: No such file or directory
./libtool: line 1129: X-g: command not found
./libtool: line 1129: X-O2: command not found
./libtool: line 1129: X-MT: command not found
./libtool: line 1129: Xdlopen.lo: command not found
./libtool: line 1129: X-MD: command not found
./libtool: line 1129: X-MP: command not found
./libtool: line 1129: X-MF: command not found
./libtool: line 1129: X.deps/dlopen.Tpo: No such file or directory
./libtool: line 1129: X-c: command not found
./libtool: line 1181: Xdlopen.lo: command not found
./libtool: line 1186: libtool: compile: cannot determine name of library object from `': command not found
make[2]: *** [dlopen.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/mirror/tmp/tmp/3/libltdl'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/mirror/tmp/tmp/3/libltdl'
make: *** [lib] Error 2
```

it's really confusing, there is no X-I command on the system in any means, somebody said it's kind of libtool bugs, and if i substitute $echo to be $ECHO, the build will be ok:(

the unbelievable thing is that after i substitute $echo to be $ECHO, run make lib, then that libtool will recover, and all $ECHO will be $echo again, and the build failed with same error....

so how to build this package without error? any suggestions?

the package name is skyeye, it's kind of simulator, you can run many kinds of embeded system on it:)
you can get the source code from

```
git://skyeye.git.sourceforge.net/gitroot/skyeye/skyeye
```

the build tutorial is here：

http://skyeye.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/SkyEye_User_Manual#1.2_Installation

Answer (score 5):

Recently I've had the same problem.

This is a bug in the script libtool that tries to execute the parameters (prefixed with X) as if there were programs, unless the variable $echo is defined.

To fix it, execute this before:

```
export echo=echo
```

Then try again.

Found here: I've found the solution in this thread: http://www.wreckedgames.com/forum/index.php?topic=1135.0

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like mismatch between the version of Libtool macro used to do the checks during `configure`, and the `ltmain.sh` file used to build `libtool`.

I would simply update `libtool` to the lastest version and run `libtoolize -f` by hand to ensure everything is up-to-date.