# error when compiling -- using autogen generated makefile

Tags: autotools, autoconf, libtool

I am trying to compile a libwebsocket package, procedure used is :--

```
./autogen 
./configure 
make
```

I am getting libtool error at make time :---

```
make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ignite/rpi_package_sb2/libwebsockets-1.0-chrome25-firefox17'
Making all in lib
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ignite/rpi_package_sb2/libwebsockets-1.0-chrome25-firefox17/lib'
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..    -Wall -std=gnu99 -pedantic  -rdynamic -fPIC -Werror -c -DINSTALL_DATADIR=\"/usr/share\" -DLWS_OPENSSL_CLIENT_CERTS=\"/etc/pki/tls/certs/\" -g -O2 -MT libwebsockets_la-libwebsockets.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libwebsockets_la-libwebsockets.Tpo -c -o libwebsockets_la-libwebsockets.lo `test -f 'libwebsockets.c' || echo './'`libwebsockets.c
../libtool: line 862: X--tag=CC: command not found
../libtool: line 895: libtool: ignoring unknown tag : command not found
../libtool: line 862: X--mode=compile: command not found
../libtool: line 1029: *** Warning: inferring the mode of operation is deprecated.: command not found
../libtool: line 1030: *** Future versions of Libtool will require --mode=MODE be specified.: command not found
../libtool: line 1173: Xgcc: command not found
../libtool: line 1173: X-DHAVE_CONFIG_H: command not found
../libtool: line 1173: X-I.: command not found
../libtool: line 1173: X-I..: command not found
../libtool: line 1173: X-Wall: command not found
../libtool: line 1173: X-std=gnu99: command not found
../libtool: line 1173: X-pedantic: command not found
../libtool: line 1173: X-rdynamic: command not found
../libtool: line 1173: X-fPIC: command not found
../libtool: line 1173: X-Werror: command not found
../libtool: line 1173: X-c: command not found
../libtool: line 1173: X-DINSTALL_DATADIR="/usr/share": No such file or directory
../libtool: line 1173: X-DLWS_OPENSSL_CLIENT_CERTS="/etc/pki/tls/certs/": No such file or directory
../libtool: line 1173: X-g: command not found
../libtool: line 1173: X-O2: command not found
../libtool: line 1173: X-MT: command not found
../libtool: line 1173: Xlibwebsockets_la-libwebsockets.lo: command not found
../libtool: line 1173: X-MD: command not found
../libtool: line 1173: X-MP: command not found
../libtool: line 1173: X-MF: command not found
../libtool: line 1173: X.deps/libwebsockets_la-libwebsockets.Tpo: No such file or directory
../libtool: line 1173: X-c: command not found
../libtool: line 1226: Xlibwebsockets_la-libwebsockets.lo: command not found
../libtool: line 1231: libtool: compile: cannot determine name of library object from `': command not found
make[2]: *** [libwebsockets_la-libwebsockets.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ignite/rpi_package_sb2/libwebsockets-1.0-chrome25-firefox17/lib'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ignite/rpi_package_sb2/libwebsockets-1.0-chrome25-firefox17'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I searched on google & found these two link both use to state to run -- `autoreconf -fi`  command

http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-870737-start-0.html
https://openlinuxforums.org/index.php?topic=3119.0

What exactly autoreconf -fi command will do ? Does it regenerate `configure.ac` file `?`
Is this sequence correct to recompile the package `?`

```
autoreconf -fi
./autogen 
./configure 
make
```

Comment: Recently I've had the same problem.

To fix it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30477516/2485895

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to build their package and their build procedure fails, I'd report it to their user's mailing list at least.  Maybe someone has figured out something that works for you.

`autoreconf -fi` will regenerate the `configure` script, rewrite `Makefile.in` and other stuff.  It does *not* regenerate `configure.ac`.  Your new sequence may or may not work.